Mirroring desktop to TV via HDMI cable stopped working
I use Arch Linux with Nvidia GPU and driver, KDE Plasma, X11, Kwin and sddm. A while ago, while using the nouveau gpu driver, I could mirror my desktop to my TV just fine. Connecting a HDMI cable between PC and TV and setting it up in KDE's System Settings was all that was required. Then suddenly one day it no longer worked. So I switched to the Nvidia driver, but has had no luck mirroring my desktop since.
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767

DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 550mm x 350mm

1920x1200     59.95 +
1920x1080     60.00*   59.99    59.94    50.00
1680x1050     59.95
1600x1200     60.00
1440x900      59.89
1366x768      59.79
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1280x960      60.00
1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
1152x864      75.00
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
720x576       50.00
720x480       59.94
640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
1920x1080     50.00*+  60.00    59.94    23.98
1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
720x576       50.00
720x480       59.94
640x480       59.93
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

It seems to me that xrandr sees the TV and reports correct settings, yet no mirroring.
